# Selecting Element from dropdown with style="display: none" doesn't work in Selenium

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<div class="InputField_Con" tabindex="-1"><div class="InputField_InputCon"><input id="TextID_Search" class="InputField_Search" type="text" role="search" autocomplete="off" style="width: 205.2px;" aria-label="* Typ:"></div></div>
```

```
<select class="Modern Val_Req " id="TextID" name="TextID" style="display: none;" aria-required="true">
  <option value="">-</option>
  <option value="1">Text1</option>
  <option value="2">Text2</option>
  <option value="3">Text3</option>
  <option value="4">Text4</option>
  <option value="5">Text5</option>
</select>
```

In the dropdown I'd like to select 'Text3', but it doesn't work.
What I tried:

```
driver.find_element("id", "TextID_Search").send_keys("Text3")
driver.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
driver.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

and as well:

```
mySelectElement = browser.find_element_by_id('TextID')
dropDownMenu = Select(mySelectElement)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "TextID")))
dropDownMenu.select_by_visible_text('Text3')
```

I'm stuck and don't know how to solve this. Need some help, thanks!

Comment: Selenium is mimicking user behavior. If the user cannot see the element ("display:none") they cannot click it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Selenium, AFAIK, you cannot select elements with `display:none`, if you want to force it, you'll need to change the display property to something visible.

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('TextID').style.display='block';")
// Your code to select and operate the Element by ID
```

An example about how to execute JS scritps from Selenium: https://pythonbasics.org/selenium-execute-javascript/

Comment: I get the following error --> AttributeError: module 'selenium' has no attribute 'execute_script'

Comment: What language are you using for selenium? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/execute_script-driver-method-selenium-python/ I've added a URL with doc about `execute_script`